# Compare two dates in a database table are equal

Tags: mysql, date

I'm new here. So, be easy on me. I have a table called 'data' in which one of the columns is 'date' stored in YYYY-MM-DD format. Here is the code that I have been working on. Basically, what I want to do is compare if two dates stored in my table are equal. But, each time I run the code, I keep getting error: Undefined offset right where the code says $lisdate[$i+1]. How do I compare the dates stored in a table? Thank you.

My code

```
$sth2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE dest_name='www.myren.net.my'");

while($rowstemp = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth2))
{
   $lisdate[] = $rowstemp['date'];  
   $lisaverage[] = $rowstemp['avg_rtt'];
}

$rows = mysql_num_rows($sth2);
$addAverage[0] = $lisaverage[0];
$numbers = 0;
$j = 0;


for($i = 0; $i<$rows; $i++)
{
   if($lisdate[$i] == $lisdate[$i+1])
   {
      $addAverage[$j] = $addAverage[$j] + $lisaverage[$i+1];
   }
   else 
   {
      $j++;
      $numbers = $numbers +1;
   }
}
```

Comment: "stored in YYYY-MM-DD format" - why are you storing them as text at all?

Comment: @Jon Skeet They are stored in DATE format in my table. I converted timestamp to date format which returned me with this "yyyy-mm-dd" format.

Comment: Why do that? Avoid converting values into text until you really need to. Now, think about when you're at the last iteration of your loop - `$lisdate[$i+1]` isn't valid at that point, is it? Remember that `$lisdate[$i]` is the *last* date... (Please format your code, as well - it's really hard to read.)

Comment: show us a print_r() of $lisdate. You can also add a check in the if !empty($lisdate[n])

Comment: How about:   `for($i = 0; $i < $rows - 1; $i++) `?  Then you won't have a problem on the last row.

Answer (score 2):

Gordon has it right. Your for loop is overrunning the end of your array because you're working with consecutive pairs of rows. Change it to read `; $i < $rows - 1;` to correct this problem.

But, you have another problem. SQL rows in result sets have an unpredictable order unless your query includes an ORDER BY clause. If these rows, without that clause, appear in ascending order by `date`, it's dumb luck. Put `ORDER BY date` in your query.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what that code in the question is attempting to achieve.

(As Ollie pointed out in his answer, it bears repeating:  the order that MySQL returns the rows is guaranteed *ONLY* if there's an `ORDER BY` clause on the query. The result from a "duplicate date" check that's being performed in the code is only going to detect a "duplicate" date value if it appears on contiguous rows.)

We see the code loading a couple of arrays, using the `date` and `avg_rtt` column values returned by the query. Then there's some manipulation on the array... the end result will be another  it's not clear what the actual *intent* of that rigmarole is, what it's actually trying to achieve.

If there are any rows It looks like there's going to be another array... if there are no "duplicate" date values found, it's going to have a single element (with the value of `rtt_avg` from the first row), and `$numbers` will be set to the number of elements in the original array.

If there is a "duplicate" date values found, the results from the code seem very odd to me, a sparsely populated array. Why?

Personally, I'd be looking to get an actual statement of the *specification*, and have the database do that processing for me, rather than mucking through two arrays.

If what we want is set of values with no duplicated date values, I'd use a `GROUP BY` and some aggregation, for example:

```
 SELECT d.dest_name
      , d.date
      , AVG(d.avg_rtt)            AS avg_avg_rtt
      , MAX(d.avg_rtt)            AS max_avg_rtt
      , MIN(d.avg_rtt)            AS min_avg_rtt
      , SUM(d.avg_rtt)            AS sum_avg_rtt
      , COUNT(1)                  AS cnt
      , COUNT(d.avg_rtt)          AS cnt_avg_rtt
      , COUNT(DISTINCT d.avg_rtt) AS cnt_distinct_avg_rtt
   FROM data d
  WHERE d.dest_name = 'www.myren.net.my'
  GROUP
     BY d.dest_name
      , d.date
  ORDER
     BY d.dest_name
      , d.date
```

If I was looking for just a count of distinct `date` values, like what `$numbers` is going to contain, then just:

```
 SELECT d.dest_name
      , COUNT(DISTINCT d.date) AS cnt_distinct_date
   FROM data d
  WHERE d.dest_name = 'www.myren.net.my'
  GROUP BY d.dest_name
  ORDER BY d.dest_name
```

The "looping through array" that the original query just looks like an odd way to achieve a result, whatever that result is supposed to be.